# Delete rows from two tables. PostgressSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

I try to delete rows from two tables. I using postgresql.

```
DELETE public.cities, public.color_schemes 
FROM public.cities
INNER JOIN public.color_schemes ON public.color_schemes.city_id = public.cities.id 
WHERE public.cities.id = 1;
```

And I get an error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "public"
LINE 1: public.
        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1
```

Comment: Why not simply run two `DELETE` statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Postgres, you can use updatable CTEs:

```
with c as (
      delete from public.color_schemes 
      where city_id = 1
     )
delete from public.cities
    where id = 1;
```

Your case is pretty simply, because the city id is in both tables.  In most complicated cases, you can return the rows deleted in the CTE using `returning` and use that in subsequent logic.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
with del as (delete from public.cities where id = 1)
delete from public.color_schemes where city_id = 1
```

Note: if there is a relationship between `cities` and `color_schemes` (as it seems here), you could as well create a foreign key on the child table that references the parent table with the `on delete cascade` clause. With this technique, the database handles the deletion in the dependent table for you under the hood when you delete a record in the parent table. Something like:

```
alter table public.color_schemes 
    add constraint color_schemes_city
    foreign key (city_id)
    references public.cities(id)
    on delete cascade;
```